# Objective-C custom memory allocator for all objects

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management

How do I properly replace standard/default memory allocator with my custom allocator for all Objective-C classes (not only for my own classes)?

This is not my first necessity, more like I'm just curious about that. For now I ended up with solution, which is seems to be working, but it is very insecure.

```
@interface NSObject(Allocator)

+ (instancetype)allocWithZone:(_NSZone*)zone;

@end

@implementation NSObject(Allocator)

+ (instancetype)allocWithZone:(_NSZone*)zone
{
    (void)zone;
    size_t sizeToAlloc = class_getInstanceSize([self class]);

    void* allocatedMemory = getSharedObjCAllocator().alloc(sizeToAlloc);
    memset(allocatedMemory, 0, sizeToAlloc);

    id resultObject = objc_constructInstance([self class], allocatedMemory);
    return resultObject;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    objc_destructInstance(self);

    if (getSharedObjCAllocator().validatePointer(self, false))
    {
        getSharedObjCAllocator().free(self);
    }
    else
    {
        ::free(self);
    }
}

@end
```

Comment: Why would you ever, ever do this?

Comment: *How do I properly replace…* You don't.

Comment: Just curious, if this could be done.